# How to specify key-value pairs

Tags: mongodb

First, let me say that I am a novice so may not ask this question as clearly as it could have been asked. here goes

From java I am calling a function FindName(int,string) (snippet below), I am getting the JSONParser errors on the DBObject ref statement. The code works fine if I hardcode the value pairs, but the goal is for the calling routine to pass different values and get the correct result.

The values being passed are valid, I even println to verify the values.

The issue seems to be that even though the values are valid int and string that mongodb does not seem to allow you to specify the names of the values that are passed to this function in the key-value pairs.

Therefore I am guessing that you need to transform the date, name values that are passed in, to a format that is acceptable to the key-value pair. The question is how to do that.

static String FindName(int date, String name)

```
 MongoClient mongoClient;
      try {
           mongoClient = new MongoClient("xxx.xx.xx.xxx",27017);
      }
      catch (UnknownHostException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return name;
      }
      DB db = mongoClient.getDB("tpfdf");
      DBCollection PNR = db.getCollection("PNR");
      DBObject ref = (DBObject) JSON.parse("{PnrByDateFlightCustom: {date:   date), pname: name'}}");

at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:208)
        at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parseObject(JSON.java:241)
        at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:205)
        at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parseObject(JSON.java:241)
        at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:205)
        at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:155)
        at com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:93)
        at com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:74)
        at MongoDB5.locatePassengerName(MongoDB5.java:38)
        at MongoDB5.main(MongoDB5.java:11)
```

Comment: This doesn't look right: {date:   date).  Try {date:   date}

Comment: Thank you but that was a finger check on my part when I was posting the copied code, but just to be clear, the error still exist...{PnrByDateFlightCustom: {date: date, name: name}}
                               ^
        at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:208)
        at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parseObject(JSON.java:241)

Answer (score 0):

Update. After many trial and errors, I found that if you dynamically build the string and then execute the ref with the dynamic string, it works.

This worked. I do not know if this is the correct way to code this, but this works so will go with it for now.

```
  String mdbStr = "{PnrByDateCustom: {date:" + value + "}}";
  System.out.println("mdbStr = " + mdbStr);

  DB db = mongoClient.getDB("tpfdf");
  DBCollection PNR = db.getCollection("PNR");
  DBObject ref = (DBObject) JSON.parse("{}");
```

//    ref = (DBObject) JSON.parse("{PnrByDateCustom: {date: value} }" );

```
  ref = (DBObject) JSON.parse(mdbStr);
```